# is getOpenGLMatrix changing rotation?

Tags: glm-math, bulletphysics

It looks like btTransform::getOpenGLMatrix is changing orientation.
The sign of x is flipped, but I don't find anything about this in the docs for getOpenGLMatrix.

```
auto t = btTransform( btQuaternion(0.7,0,0,0.7), bt(0,0,0));
glm::mat4 ogl_t;
t.getOpenGLMatrix(glm::value_ptr(ogl_t));

glm::vec3 scale;
glm::quat orientation;
glm::vec3 translation;
glm::vec3 skew;
glm::vec4 perspective;

glm::decompose(ogl_t,scale,orientation,translation,skew,perspective); // returns true

assert(fabs(orientation.x - 0.7 ) < 0.02); // fails because x is -0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be the ***same*** orientation.

Let's look at Quaternion's definition `[x y z w]`: -

```
// RotationAngle is in radians
x = RotationAxis.x * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
y = RotationAxis.y * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
z = RotationAxis.z * sin(RotationAngle / 2)
w = cos(RotationAngle / 2)
```

**Example :** `[x=0.7,y=0,z=0,w=0.7]` is the same as `[x=-0.7,y=0,z=0,w=-0.7]`
Thus, your experimental result is not an evidence that orientation is ***changed***.

**Read more :**

- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/  (long article)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765363/can-different-quaternions-represent-the-same-orientation    (proof)